# Unable to clean up mess surrounding `./usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5' before installing another version: Read-only file system

Tags: raspbian, readwrite, dpkg

I have the following error, how can I fix it please ?

```
root@raspberrypi:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf# sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
Correcting dependencies... Done 
The following extra packages will be installed:   gcc-5-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libjack-jackd2-0 liborc-0.4-0 libstdc++6 libtag1v5 libtag1v5-vanilla   libvpx3 libwibble-dev Suggested packages:   gstreamer1.0-tools jackd2 
The following packages will be REMOVED:   libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a 
The following NEW packages will be installed:   gcc-5-base libtag1v5 libtag1v5-vanilla libvpx3 
The following packages will be upgraded:   gstreamer1.0-plugins-good libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libjack-jackd2-0 liborc-0.4-0 libstdc++6 libwibble-dev 
9 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 2 to remove and 842 not upgraded. 
1 not fully installed or removed. 
Need to get 0 B/11.9 MB of archives. 
After this operation, 5,727 kB of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y 
(Reading database ... 105863 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack .../gcc-5-base_5.3.1-8+rpi1_armhf.deb ... 
Unpacking gcc-5-base:armhf (5.3.1-8+rpi1) ... 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-5-base_5.3.1-8+rpi1_armhf.deb (--unpack):  
unable to clean up mess surrounding `./usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5' before installing another version: 
Read-only file system dpkg-deb: error: 
subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
Errors were encountered while processing:  /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-5-base_5.3.1-8+rpi1_armhf.deb 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: "...Read-only file system dpkg-deb: error:..." That looks like a file-system has become *read-only* which can happen if an RPi is not shut-down properly or there are power supply issues. I'd look to sort that out with a reboot (that should run `fsck` to fix any corruption if possible) first.  This should be safe to do as you do not seem to modifying any packages vital to the actual operation of the system.  However - what is your Power Supply rated at/supplying?